# Get the latest data based on the latest date - MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This is how my tables look in my database:
I have 2 tables:

```
 1. Location = ID, Name
 2. Product = ProdID, LocationID, CreatedDate

-------------------------------------------------
| ID           | Location     | CreatedDate     
-------------------------------------------------
| 1234         | Location 1   | 2016-11-17 12:39
| 4567         | Location 1   | 2016-11-17 12:39 
| 8978         | Location 1   | 2016-11-17 12:39       
| 8978         | Location 2   | 2016-11-17 13:39
| 2578         | Location 1   | 2016-11-17 12:39
| 1234         | Location 2   | 2016-11-18 12:39
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve a table like below:

```
----------------------------------------------
| Location 1   | Location 2   | Location 3   |
----------------------------------------------
| 1234         | 1234         |              |
| 4567         |              |              |
| 8978         | 8978         | 8978         |
| 2578         | 2578         | 2578         |
----------------------------------------------
```

Also an addition to the above table I want a query to get the total amount the last scanned unique items on each location:

```
Location 1 count = 1
Location 2 count = 1
Location 3 count = 2
```

**Explanation**: The above table shows a list of different items in our warehouse.
Basically if item 1234 scanned on Location 1 at 12:00 and later on scanned at 13:00 to Location 2, then the query must only get the data from Location 2, since it's the last update based on the date.

Comment: Provide the sample data. You have provided the expected result. But sample data is missing.

Comment: `SELECT '1234' \`Location 1\`, '1234' \`Location 2\`,'' \`Location 3\` UNION ...`

Comment: It can be really hard to answer questions like these without sample data.  Take a look this [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056), which asked for tips on how to post a good SQL question.  It is also worth reading this guide from the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Following the advice on these pages should increase the likelihood of getting the right answer.

Comment: @MishMish what is the datatype for column `ProdID`?

Comment: They are both Int for ID and ProdID.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below queries

For requirement1

```
select 
    case when Location1 = 0 then null else Location1 end Location1,
    case when Location2 = 0 then null else Location2 end Location2,
    case when Location3 = 0 then null else Location3 end Location3
from(
    SELECT 
        SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 1' then id else 0 end) Location1, 
        SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 2' then id else 0 end) Location2, 
        SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 3' then id else 0 end) Location3
    from Product
    group by ProdID) t1;
```

Below is the result of above query

[image]

For requirement2,

```
select 
     sum(case when Location2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) Location1,
     sum(case when Location3 = 0 and Location2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) Location2,
     sum(case when Location3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) Location3
from(
    SELECT 
         SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 1' then id else 0 end) Location1, 
         SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 2' then id else 0 end) Location2, 
         SUM(case when location_id = 'Location 3' then id else 0 end) Location3
    from Product
    group by id) t1;
```

Below is the result for above query

[image]

**Note: The above queries will work only if ProdID is integer.**

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: Hi Viki
Your query works really nice, but it seems very static. I'm planning to add up to 17 locations at the end. A dynamic approach would make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to inner join, obviously, on ID = LocationID.

Beyond that, this is about your 'where' clause.  You'll need subqueries that get the max(date) of each item, which I'm guessing is the part you were missing.

Comment: Yes I just updated my question with how my current table looks like